# When I execute the Switch Commands through the plink, output was not present in the xx.txt

Tags: python-2.7

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY>plink -ssh 1.1.1.1 -l admn -pw 
password <c:\outputfile\output.txt\> c:\outputfile\output_result.txt
Using username "admn".
```

When I executed the above in command prompt, the command which is present in the output.txt file is output_result.txt but the output for the command is not present in the output_result.txt file.

output.txt contains the following commands

```
help
uname
exit
logout
```

After execution of the plink command,

`output_result.txt` contains the following output for the above commands

```
helpunameexitlogout
```

can any one help me to find out.

Comment: Is `admn` correct?

Comment: yes username for the switch is admn

Comment: if we entered the username and password are wrong, we will get the error message as "Access Denied"